# Multiplying ints on PHP?

Tags: php, int

I am trying to multiply these two ints together.

```
        $value = calculateCateringCosts($i, $db);//int 1
        echo "<td>$value * $partySize</td>";
```

However this is the result I get:
    20 * 150

Comment: What do the variables `$i` and `$db` contain? What does the function `calculateCateringCosts` do? What does `$partySize` contain? As for why it is printing the literal character `*` in the result, it's because you're printing it as a string (as in, wrapped in quotes). You need something like `echo "<td>".($value * $partySize)."</td>";` to print the *actual* product.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    $value = calculateCateringCosts($i, $db);//int 1
    echo "<td>".($value * $partySize)."</td>";
```